# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-1.6-go_1.6.2-0ubuntu5~16.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):

Tags: golang

When I am running sudo apt-get -f install, it shows dpkg: error processing. Please find the complete logs below and advise how to solve this. I am running VB 5.0.10 with Ubuntu 16.04 and already installed go 1.8 and its working fine

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils containerd gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop:i386 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:i386 gir1.2-glib-2.0:i386
  gir1.2-pango-1.0:i386 libc6-dev:i386 libcaca-dev libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo-script-interpreter2:i386 libdmx-dev libdmx1
  libedata-cal-1.2-28 libepoxy-dev libexpat1-dev:i386 libfontconfig1-dev:i386 libfontenc-dev libfreetype6-dev:i386 libfribidi-dev
  libfs-dev libfs6 libgeocode-glib0 libgirepository-1.0-1:i386 libglu1-mesa-dev libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libgweather-common
  libharfbuzz-gobject0:i386 libharfbuzz-icu0:i386 libice-dev:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libilmbase12 libjpeg-turbo8-dev
  liblzo2-2:i386 libopenexr22 libpangox-1.0-0 libpciaccess-dev libpcre16-3:i386 libpcre3-dev:i386 libpcre32-3:i386
  libpcrecpp0v5:i386 libpng12-dev:i386 libsdl1.2debian libslang2-dev libsm-dev:i386 libsm6:i386 libvte-common libxaw7-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev:i386 libxcb-shm0-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxfont-dev libxkbfile-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxmuu-dev
  libxpm-dev libxrender-dev:i386 libxres-dev libxss-dev libxt-dev libxv-dev libxvmc-dev libxxf86dga-dev linux-headers-4.4.0-64
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66 linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-67
  linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70 linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-libc-dev:i386 mir-client-platform-mesa-dev nettle-dev par2 python-cairo python-gobject-2
  runc ubuntu-fan x11proto-bigreqs-dev x11proto-dmx-dev x11proto-dri3-dev x11proto-fonts-dev x11proto-present-dev
  x11proto-resource-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-video-dev x11proto-xcmisc-dev x11proto-xf86bigfont-dev x11proto-xf86dga-dev
  x11proto-xf86dri-dev zlib1g-dev:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  golang-1.6-go
Suggested packages:
  bzr
The following packages will be upgraded:
  golang-1.6-go
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
44 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
(Reading database ... 453044 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../golang-1.6-go_1.6.2-0ubuntu5~16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking golang-1.6-go (1.6.2-0ubuntu5~16.04.2) over (1.6.2-0ubuntu5~16.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-1.6-go_1.6.2-0ubuntu5~16.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/go-1.6/src', which is also in package golang-1.6-race-detector-runtime 0.0+svn252922-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-1.6-go_1.6.2-0ubuntu5~16.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: First, clean up your system: `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Second, look at the error message for the 'trying to overwrite' string. Read that entire line (it wraps around) carefully. Each file in Ubuntu can be provided by only one package (few exceptions). When two packages try to provide the same file, they *conflict*. Decide which one you want and uninstall the other.